# Air Datepicker select more than one time on multiselect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I came across this jquery datetimepicker called the Air Datepicker and is using it for my project.

[Air Picker](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/)

I have some issues selecting multiple timeslots on the same day for the multiselect. Would appreciate it if someone is able to guide me on what changes can be made to achieve it.

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="suggest.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>"/>
                <!-- Vote Date Options -->
                <label class="control-label" for="vote_date">Available Dates & Time (Up to 5)</label>
                <input id="vote_date" name="vote_date" type='text' class="datepicker-here form-control" data-timepicker="true" data-language="en"  data-multiple-dates="5" data-multiple-dates-separator=", " placeholder="Select Dates Available for Meeting"/>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Suggest</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Javascript

```
//Set End Vote Date

var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

end_vote_date.selectDate(date);

$('#vote_date').datepicker({
    language: 'en',
    startDate: date,
    minDate: date,
}).data('datepicker');
```

Comment: show us your implementation...

Comment: Hi, I have included a part of my code in the post above. I am basically using the default Air Datepicker but with Multiselect settings and time enabled. I think it is an issue with the datepicker itself but probably can override it and fix it with some changes in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js?1.1.2"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <input id="vote_date" name="vote_date" type='text' class="datepicker-here" data-timepicker="true" data-language="en"  data-multiple-dates="5" data-multiple-dates-separator=", " placeholder="Select Dates Available for Meeting"/>
        </form>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/i18n/datepicker.en.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var arr = ['01 Dec, 2021 10:01 am', '02 Dec, 2021 10:02 am', '03 Dec, 2021 10:03 am', '06 Dec, 2021 10:06 am', '07 Dec, 2021 10:07 am', '08 Dec, 2021 10:08 am', '09 Dec, 2021 10:09 am', '10 Dec, 2021 10:10 am'];

        $.each(arr, function(i,v) {
            $('#vote_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').selectDate(new Date(v));
        });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).